# QRegexp Ленивая квантификация

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, qt

Есть строка в формате `x-y`. Нужна регулярка, которая будет захватывать x и y. 
Я сразу выбрал такой вариант:

```
QRegExp regexp("(.+)-(.+)");
```

Но для случая `-100--500` он работает не корректно, захватывая `-100-` и `500`.
[Пример](https://regex101.com/r/dZ7sM6/1)

Первая мысль была что нужно сделать первую захватываемую групу "ленивой"

```
QRegExp regexp("(.+?)-(.+)");
```

В теории все работает([пример](https://regex101.com/r/dZ7sM6/2)), но на практике `QRegExp` не поддерживает ленивую квантификацию. Поэтому приходится делать так

```
QRegExp regexp("(.+)-(.+)");
regexp.setMinimal(true);
```

Но теперь у меня обе группы "ленивые" `(.+?)-(.+?)`. Разумеется ничего не работает. [Пример](https://regex101.com/r/dZ7sM6/3).
Ну это ничего страшного можно ведь указать, что вторая группа должна продолжаться до конца строки.

```
QRegExp regexp("(.+)-(.+)$");
regexp.setMinimal(true);
```

В теории все работает. [Пример](https://regex101.com/r/dZ7sM6/4). На практике нет. `QRegExp` теперь по какой-то причине перестает "ленится" и захватывает `-100-` и `500`. Для такого регулярного выражения `setMinimal` вообще не оказывает никакого эффекта.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QRegExp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString str("-100--500");
    QRegExp regexp("(.+)-(.*)$");

    regexp.setMinimal(true);
    regexp.indexIn(str);
    std::cout << "1)" << regexp.cap(1).toStdString() << std::endl; //-100-
    std::cout << "2)" << regexp.cap(2).toStdString() << std::endl; //500

    regexp.setMinimal(false);
    regexp.indexIn(str);
    std::cout << "1)" << regexp.cap(1).toStdString() << std::endl; //-100-
    std::cout << "2)" << regexp.cap(2).toStdString() << std::endl; //-500

    return a.exec();
}
```

Собственно вопрос, как мне извлечь x и y из строки `x-y` используя `QRegExp`? Варианты с бустом, C++11, Qt 4.6.3+ и заменой . на \d не подходят.

Comment: А может проще? [`-[0-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/eZ9yM3/1)? Или данные могут быть разные? Или обязательно нужны 2 захватывающие подмаски? Если там всегда в конце группы будет буква/цифра/_, можно и так попробовать - [`"^(.+)\\b-(.+)$"`](https://regex101.com/r/eZ9yM3/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Разные. Да и обычное число можно написать как 3E8, или 2.71, или 3,14.

Comment: Если там всегда в конце группы будет буква/цифра/_, можно и так попробовать - [`"^(.+)\\b-(.+)$"`](https://regex101.com/r/eZ9yM3/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, не всегда. Вполне естественно написать `-100 - -500`

Comment: Используйте https://regex101.com/r/dZ7sM6/6

Comment: @Visman: Нет в QRegExp поддержки lookbehind. :(

Comment: Трудно тестировать без более конкретных примеров.  А что если пойти трудным путем? [`^([-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)\\s*-\\s*([-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/eZ9yM3/4)?

Comment: Попробуйте так: `(-?[^-]+)-(.*)` вернее так наверно: `(-{0,1}[^-]+)-(.*)`

Comment: @Tunker, немного изменил `(.[^-]*)-(.*)`, в принципе работает. Но теперь не получается сделать так `QString format(%1-%2); QRegExp regex(format.arg("(.+)").("(.+)"));` Я, конечно, не писал про это в вопросе, но мне очень хотелось бы сделать регулярку из формата :) Надо теперь подумать как это сделать

Comment: @Tunker, напишите как ответ, хоть плюс поставлю

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb А что мешает использовать `QString format(%1-%2); QRegExp regex(format.arg("(-?[^-]+)").("(-?[^-]+)"));`? + Ещё `\\s*` добавить вокруг `-`? [Вот так](https://regex101.com/r/eZ9yM3/5).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. Ничего. Просто если формат станет например `%1><%2` придется и регулярку менять. Надо подумать как это дело обобщить, чтоб не переписывать в случае чего много кода

Comment: Если есть возможность, переходите на Qt5 и используйте `QRegularExpression`, там гораздо меньше багов, и ленивые квантификаторы работают вперемешку с жадными.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, увы такой возможности нету

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так: `(-?[^-]+)-(.*)` вернее так наверно: `(-{0,1}[^-]+)-(.*)`

Comment: А в чём разница между `?` и `{0,1}` ?

Comment: Для самого регекспа нет разницы, но в вопросе речь шла о библиотеке `QRegExp` который не поддерживает ленивую квантификацию.

Comment: А как это различие связано с ленивостью/неленивостью?

Comment: Второй вариант не использует ленивость, и работает именно в той программе, которую использует автор вопроса. Для других библиотек оба эти варианты будут равнозначны

Comment: Ок. Спасибо. Буду иметь ввиду. Рекомендую не использовать библиотеку в которой `?` и `{0,1}` - не одно и то же.